# Load unstructured data into tabular form in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

am not sure if it unstructured or some one just copy pasted data from web into excel.
data is not consistent,data is all over the places.example city southam is in columnD and ColumnB in source File.
Below is example (replaced original data) and i want to transform as below in tabular.

[Source Data A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNu0f.png)

[Destination Data A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc4Rf.png)

[Source Data B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6w3g.png)

[Destination Data B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xz5V.png)

Comment: Assuming that the same pattern follows in the Source tables, it looks like, you have to use a cursor and read each row - column and extract data. You may have to create an identity column, to loop

Comment: thank you,how do you define which is column header and which is data. example city name for some records in column D and for some records Column B.by reading data with out column header with cursor,how column header will be assigned?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it. it seems that it is possible to get cleaned as much as possible only. The rest needs to be manually done.